Is a monoid endomorphism determined by its right inverse?
Let us consider a commutative monoid $(M,*,1)$, a map (not necessary homomorphism) $f:M\to M$, and a monoid homormophism $h\colon M \to M$ such that
$h(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in M$ (or shortly $h\circ f = id_M$).
Clearly, given an endomorphism $h'$ satisfying the condition ($h'\circ f = id_M$) we know that $h'|_X = h|_X$, where $X=Im(f)\cup \{1\}$.

Does it hold that $f$ determines $h$ (implying $h' = h$)?
Or is there a commutative monoid and $f$ with two distinct
endomorphisms $h$ and $h'$ such that both are left inverses to $f$?


Perhaps obvious, but if $M$ is finite then $f$ is a bijection, so it has exactly one left inverse $h$. So for the question to be interesting we must consider $M$ infinite.

The answer is no, even if $f$ is also a homomorphism!
Let $M$ be the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$.
Let $f : M \to M$ be the homomorphism defined by
$$(x_0, x_1, \dots) \mapsto (0, x_0, x_1, \dots)$$
Let $h : M \to M$ be the homomorphism defined by
$$(x_0, x_1, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, \dots)$$
Let $h' : M \to M$ be the homomorphism defined by
$$(x_0, x_1, \dots) \mapsto (x_0 + x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$$
Then $h \circ f = h' \circ f$, but $h \neq h'$.
